# Get java.lang.IllegalStateException

Tags: selenium-webdriver, firefoxdriver

I am a beginner to testing. I want to launch Firefox browser. Can anyone explain me the error of below code?

```java
package Script;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class TestEbay_login {
    public static void main (String []arStrings) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Users\\Senani\\Downloads\\Programs\\geckodriver-v0.23.0-win64.exe");  
        WebDriver driver = new  FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.google.com");
    }
}
```

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver
>   executable does not exist:
>   C:\Users\Senani\Downloads\Programs\geckodriver.exe

Comment: Just a guess, but it seems to me that the property only stores the directory path to the geckodriver and then always looks for `geckodriver.exe`. Now you have `geckodriver-v0.23.0-win64.exe`, so as a quick idea you can rename it to `geckodriver.exe` and see what happens.

Comment: Please also make sure all the files are extracted from zip and the path you are storing the driver executable is accessible by a program.\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the error message the test is looking for `..\Downloads\Programs\geckodriver.exe` while you have `..\Downloads\Programs\geckodriver-v0.23.0-win64.exe`.

Renaming `geckodriver-v0.23.0-win64.exe` to `geckodriver.exe` should solve the issue.